# React - how to pass props with different names to same component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a card component that receives a `title`, `description`, and `image` props, however the data that I receive from two different sources labels these props differently.

Source 1 (`carouselContent`):

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "title 1",
    "description": "Description text 1",
    "image": {
      "fluid": {
        "src": "/get-job-you-want.jpg?w=800&q=50"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "title 2",
    "description": "Description text 2",
    "image": {
      "fluid": {
        "src": "/framing-a-high-deck-1.jpg?w=800&q=50"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This passed onto an `<ImageSlider/>` component like so:

`<ImageSlider data={carouselContent} />`

Then next source (`relatedPrograms`) looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "fullProgramName": "title 1",
    "id": "1",
    "metaDescription": "description 1",
    "heroImage": {
      "fluid": {
        "src": "/denys-nevozhai-100695.jpg?w=350&h=196&q=50&fit=scale"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "fullProgramName": "title 2",
    "id": "2",
    "metaDescription": "description 2",
    "heroImage": null
  }
]
```

and to be called like so:
`<ImageSlider data={relatedPrograms} />`

How do I structure the component to be able to handle both the `title` and `image` coming from source 1 and the `fullProgramName` and `heroImage` coming from source 2?

Comment: Can you just normalize this data before you pass it to your component?  This doesn't need to be a react-specific problem. `const normalizedData = data.map(item => ({...item, foo: 'bar'}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick suggestion on how to map your two data sources to have a common shape.  Obviously you'd modify this to contain the properties that were important to your `ImageSlider` component that renders the images.  Here I have just picked a couple fields from your example data. The important feature here is that no matter where the data come from (carousel versus related), you transform them to represent a set of images, where their origin doesn't matter and they are indistinguishable to the `ImageSlider`.  `ImageSlider` probably just cares about relevant image data, so decide on a shape that represents your basic image data.

Also a codesandbox for this: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-morning-obwld

```
const normalizedCarousel = carouselContent.map((item) => ({
  id: item.id,
  name: item.title,
  src: item.image.fluid.src
}));

const normalizedRelated = relatedPrograms.map((item) => ({
  id: item.id,
  name: item.fullProgramName,
  src: item.heroImage?.fluid.src
}));

const ImageSlider = ({ header, data }) => {
  // This component now just renders a list with relevant props
  // but in the real app would render the slider.
  return (
    <>
      <h2>{header}</h2>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => {
          const { id, name, src } = item;
          return (
            <li>
              Id: {id}, Name: {name}, Src: {src}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ImageSlider header="Carousel" data={normalizedCarousel} />
      <ImageSlider header="Related" data={normalizedRelated} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can preprocess or combine your data just before passing it as a prop to your component or you can use a secondary prop and populate only the values from your secondary data source.

```
const a =[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "title 1",
    "description": "Description text 1",
    "image": {
      "fluid": {
        "src": "/get-job-you-want.jpg?w=800&q=50"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "title 2",
    "description": "Description text 2",
    "image": {
      "fluid": {
        "src": "/framing-a-high-deck-1.jpg?w=800&q=50"
      }
    }
  }
]

const b = [
  {
    "fullProgramName": "title 1",
    "id": "1",
    "metaDescription": "description 1",
    "heroImage": {
      "fluid": {
        "src": "/denys-nevozhai-100695.jpg?w=350&h=196&q=50&fit=scale"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "fullProgramName": "title 2",
    "id": "2",
    "metaDescription": "description 2",
    "heroImage": null
  }
]

const c = []
a.forEach((val, idx) => {
    c.push({
        title: val.title,
        image: val.image,
        fullProgramName: b[idx].fullProgramName,
        heroImage: b[idx].heroImage
    });
})
```

Then you can easily pass that copy of data to your component